# Create-React-App Proxy in Production Build

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app with an express backend. I have the backend running on port 3001, and the frontend runs through port 3000 when in dev mode. I have `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` in my package.json and the api works perfectly.

When I use yarn build, however, and then run `serve -s build`, the api calls are simply not being made. I'm not sure why it doesn't work in production, when it does in dev.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 28):

The proxy feature isn't meant for production.

This might help further explain: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1087#issuecomment-262611096

Comment: Then what is the work around in production ?

Comment: @darth vader I would suggest using [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) as I believe it is the common practice among production envs.

Comment: Yes I found Nginx is good in serving static files which do serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Make rather an ENV file and give the path of your backend like this - REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:5500 (change port according to your port)
and whereever you are calling api - (process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL/your url) .
It will work perfectly in production.