# MERN stack - The link, as the endpoint of the node, does not work in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

React.js: i have a google login button, that looks something like this

```
const GoogleButton = () => (
<a href='/auth/google' >
    <div className='google-icon-wrapper'>
        <img className='google-icon' src= {googleLogo} alt='Google logo'/>    
    </div>
    <p className ='google-btn-text'>
        Sign in with google
    </p>
</a>
```

)

React.js (http-proxy-middleware) in development mode i also have proxy settings

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/auth/", { target: "http://localhost:5000/" }));
  app.use(proxy("/api/", { target: "http://localhost:5000/" }));
};
```

Node.js : I have this endpoint, and it doesn't work on production
since the proxy does not work on the production

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: SCOPE,
  access_type: 'offline',
})
```

);

**when I click on the button, on the production, react sends me to the page - for example: [www.example.com/auth/google](http://www.example.com/auth/google) - but must call node endpoint ** but when i make a fetch request then the node endpoint works, for example, if I do this: fetch ('/api/google'), it will work ..

**UPDATE** : the problem was in the React serviceWorker.js - PWA ... it cached the result and the link .. i think not sure ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are identifying `http://localhost:5000/` as the host and port on prod for node.js explicitly it can be tricky.
Some platforms, like `heroku` are binding the *port* automatically so you don't know exactly which is it. Try to use a env variable for `HOST` getting from `env` and try to bind in the proxy like `http://localhost:${host}/`

Comment: not sure it will work ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911067/create-react-app-proxy-in-production-build

Comment: oh ok I was focused on another part, sorry